# Trying to configure two USB drives for Samba server, permissions allow access to one but not the other on PC?

Tags: raspbian, server, permissions, samba

On my raspberry pi 3 that has Samba and Ntfs-3g running Raspian I have two USB drives mounted to two folders (from `lsblk`)

[image]

Then I have added the following code to the bottom of the samba configure file smb.conf:

[image]

Now Whenever I try to access on my windows PC, I can access the one of the USB drives, but then I am unable to access my other USB due to permissions

[image]

Is this due to the creation of masks as that affects permissions?

Is there any way to have both USB drives accessible at the same time?

Permissions

```
drwxr-xr-x  12 pi   pi    8192 Jan  1  1970 External
drwxr-xr-x  12 pi   pi    8192 Jan  1  1970 External2
```

Comment: Your question may be a bit ambiguous: Is the problem that you can access both drives, but not at the same time?, or is it that you can always access one, but never the other? Also, your underlying Linux permissions will have an effect - how are they set (ls -l)?

Comment: Please don't use images for text output. Instead insert the text direct into the question.

Comment: I can only access the silver directory and never the toshiba directory. I also cannot delete files in the silver directory that i can access either My permissions are                                                                                           
drwxr-xr-x  12 pi   pi    8192 Jan  1  1970 External
drwxr-xr-x  12 pi   pi    8192 Jan  1  1970 External2

Comment: I suggest to have the silver driver first fully connecting with all access needed. So please unplug Thoshiba. Whats the ```/etc/fstab``` looking like?

Comment: (btw: I am wondering if this could be a power issue using a 2.5Amps power supply for 1raspi  + 2usb hard drives)

Comment: The mask sets are off, `Toshiba` mask is set to globally permissive and does not match fs and may be cause of failure (check logs) if it expects that permission or tried to set it,  The mask set for `silver` and current permissions on fs will not allow another user to create files or folders in the directory